Integrand must equal zero
Apprently I have to write some addtional wordage to give "some context" to this question....
as follows...
In my fluid dynamics, "Notes on CFD, General Principles, Greenshields" on pg 13, on the disscussion and proof of Conservation of mass,  it states;
$\int_V[\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \bullet (\rho u) ] dV = 0$
"since the integral is valid for any volume V, it follows that the integrand  (in [...]) must equal 0, resulting in the following."
$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \bullet (\rho u) = 0$
Can somebody explain to me why the integrand must equal zero for any volume?

If the integrand function is positive in a point, by continuity it should be positive in a ball centered at the point and so also the integral on the ball should be positive, against the hypothesis that the integral is zero on every set.
The same happens if you suppose the integrand function negative in the point, so by exclusion it should be zero.
